# Are references orthogonal to pointers?

Tags: c++

The question is meant as language orthogonal(as is in lack of redundency) features. References (never null[1]) in C++ *can* be implemented with pointers while compilers check for the semantic differences. There are languages like Java or C# that only have references (maybe null) but no pointers and C has it the other way round. So one is sufficent for a *complete* language. Is the behaviour in C++ different enough to be orthogonal?

[1] You can de-reference a `nullptr` but that is undefined.

Comment: >  So one is sufficent for a complete language.  < No. Manual memory management, access to special memory regions in embedded programming is impossible w/out pointers. Also, I've never heard any definition of _complete_ language beyond Turing completeness. Care to elaborate?

Comment: There are Turing-complete programming languages that have neither pointers nor references nor any equivalent concept as part of the language.

Comment: Yes, they are different enough. References are value category aware, while pointers can only refer to lvalues.

Comment: In c++ a pointer is a declared variable that can be on the stack or on the heap where a reference does not for it references an already created instance to another variable.

Comment: References in Java or C# should not be directly compared to references in C++. It's just a same word being reused.

Comment: C# does have pointers, albeit only available in an `unsafe` context..

Comment: It isn't very clear what you mean by "orthogonal" exactly. Do they present different sets of features to the programmer? Yes they do. Do these sets have a non-empty intersection? Yes they do. Is one a subset of another? Nope.

Comment: @myaut I already felt that "complete" is the wrong term. I mean something like "for usefullness required".

Comment: @Peter Are you talking about esoteric things like Brainfuck?

Comment: How can this question generate a constructive and clear answer? Seems too vague.

Comment: @n.m. You comment clearly answers it for me. They are not orthogonal then.

Comment: @FrancisCugler stacks or heaps have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to reference collapsing rules (§8.3.2), references has become
quite useful; they now support "perfect forwarding" something not
possible with pointers. Example:

```
template<typename T>
class some_container
{
public:
    // ... lots of other stuff
    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        T* ptr = find_slot_for_new_data();
        new (ptr) T( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
};
```

This will construct a `T` in-place, (`emplace_xxx` are delegating constructors)
and it will use 
"perfect forwarding" to do so, that is;

`T&&` where `T` is deduced will preserve the:

- type
- value category
- cv-qualifiers

This is not possible with pointers.

Answer (score -2):

References are nothing more then stricter pointers in C++,  since you can "convert" a reference to a pointer by taking its address.
That's far from saying they are redundant, but they are the opposite of orthogonal. They essentially do the same thing.

Comment: *Nothing more* - That's false. A reference type has value category awareness.

Comment: You got that backwards, stricter pointers was meant as having additional properties, like beeing defined as non-null. There is a big overlap which is the opposite of orthogonal.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a difference between pointers and references to consider.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
   // Compiles and it contains pointers to ints 
   std::vector<int*> vpInts; 
   return 0;
}
```

Versus

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Does not compile
    std::vector<int&> vrInts;
    return 0;
}
```

The second case is illegal this is especially shown in MSVS's compiler error from MSVS2017 CE.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test1z, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(774): error C2528: 'pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(984): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(441): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(493): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<int &>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(701): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<int &>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\test1z\test1z\main.cpp(15): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<int &,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(775): error C2528: 'const_pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(798): error C2535: 'int &(*std::allocator<_Ty>::address(int &) noexcept const)': member function already defined or declared
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(792): note: see declaration of 'std::allocator<_Ty>::address'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(918): error C2528: 'pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(988): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<int &>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(919): error C2528: 'const_pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(938): error C2528: '<template-parameter>': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(944): error C2528: '<template-parameter>': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(1031): error C2535: 'int &(*std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::address(int &) const)': member function already defined or declared
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(1025): note: see declaration of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::address'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(159): error C2528: 'abstract declarator': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(444): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Is_simple_alloc<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(159): error C2528: '<template-parameter>': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(161): error C2528: 'abstract declarator': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(161): error C2528: '<template-parameter>': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(452): error C2528: '<template-parameter>': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(176): error C2528: 'pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(497): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Simple_types<int &>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0(177): error C2528: 'const_pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(951): error C2535: 'void std::vector<int &,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty)': member function already defined or declared
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(945): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<int &,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(1033): error C2535: 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int &>>> std::vector<int &,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int &>>>,_Ty)': member function already defined or declared
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(1027): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<int &,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(1634): error C2528: 'data': pointer to reference is illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\vector(1639): error C2528: 'data': pointer to reference is illegal
1>Done building project "Test1z.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Basically in C++  a pointer itself is a declared variable that takes up memory either on the stack or the heap  where a reference may or may not for it references an already created object or variable that is already in memory. It depends on how the compiler will treat it; some compilers will optimize the memory footprint away by using move semantics by pushing and popping value in and out of registers while a pointer variable will always take up a specified amount of memory. There are similarities such that a pointer does point to the memory address of another variable or object and that a reference references the memory address of an already created instance of another variable or object.

Comment: "The second case is illegal especially in MSVS"  - what do you mean "especially in msvs"?  Also, a reference takes up space.   It has to store what it's referring to.  A reference is a pointer under the covers, it just has additional compile-time behavior.

Comment: It is unspecified it the standard whether a reference has storage or not. This is different from the "as-if" rule, a reference is allowed to not have storage even in a context where you can tell the difference. In practice, this rarely is the case.

Comment: The heap/stack thing has no relevance. References can refer to objects in either. Pointers can point to objects in either. Pointers, also being objects, can also *be* in either.

Comment: I'm guessing people do not truly understand English. I stated that a Pointer can be on the stack or on the heap that is designated by memory where a reference itself refers to an object already in memory either it be on the stack or on the heap. Obviously the object that a reference refers to can be either... I edited the answer to make it more clear. Maybe I should write my answers at a 4th grade reading level.

Comment: Oh dear. Well, while you're at it, you could also mention that a pointer can be in static storage too. Why stop at stack and heap?

Comment: @FrancisCugler that would be a good idea as the majority are not native speakers and have various levels of education.

Comment: @juanchopanza true; but I was just trying to demonstrate how the compiler treats the two, how they are similar and are different while keeping it simple. I didn't want to get into static, volatile or mutable terminology...